# SQL Case with sum and normal value

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, aggregate

Below is my SQL query

```
select                
 case when x < 2 then  a 
 when x = 0 then Max(a) end a
 ,case when x < 2 then  b
 when x = 0 then  Sum(b) end b
from T
```

How can we do this? I am using right now Union to get the required result. Looking for a better way to do this.

Comment: Could you please show your table scheme, example data and what result expected?

Comment: Right now I am getting my result something like this.
SELECT a,b
FROM T
where x= 0
union all

SELECT MAX(a), SUM(b)
FROM T
where x = 2

Comment: Your solution in the comment should have good performance and it's easy to read. Why you don't like it?

Comment: in both cases your second when will not execute. Because x<2 also includes x=0

Answer (score 0):

You can get these aggregate values into a variable and use it.

```
DECLARE @maxA int;
DECLARE @sumB int;

SELECT @maxA = max(a),@sumB = sum(b) FROM t;

SELECT CASE
           WHEN x < 2 THEN a
           WHEN x = 0 THEN @maxA
       END a ,
       CASE
           WHEN x < 2 THEN b
           WHEN x = 0 THEN @sumB
       END b
FROM T
```

Comment: Which one is more efficient ?  I am doing like this....
SELECT a,b
FROM T

union all

SELECT MAX(a), SUM(b)
FROM T

Comment: I wonder how you managed to get the output using the mentioned query.
Also, you can check the check the execution plan to figure out which is more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CASE When conditions inside the Aggregate functions.

i.e.

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN x < 2 THEN a WHEN x = 0 THEN @maxA END) AS sum_a
```